# Store pass for FTP and secure communication with PHP

Tags: php, android, security

i have two questions...both of them are about security issues on android app..

1. From my app are photos sent to my ftp server,so i need to have stored ftp,user and pass..what is the best way to to that? I am affraid that these values can be easily read from code by reverse engineering..i was thinking about shared preferences but i think it is not enouhg...or to send request to my server which returns pass to ftp server (this is part of second question:)
2. In app a communicate with php server (create order then in app biling and finally confirmation that order was already paid...i have to write secure communication between android and php..(now android send json data by post method to php server..so if somebody cinds out url and json format of data..he is could create ordef and confirm it)..in app is no login or registration process..i was thinking abou asymetric cryptography with public key on android and private key on server..or  maybe SSL is a solution..i am very confused so any  advices are welcome..

I dont know how to secure app whne reverse engineering of apk is possible..

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of using FTP create simple API for your application which allows to post an image. That would be better and more secure solution. Android has few built-in methods for HTTP POST requests.
2. SSL secures just communication between. Most of commonly known applications doesnt store password in files, just use API request to validate credentials and obtain token which will be used in future requests. You can set timeout for this token and create one token per device. This is much safier, because its easier to cancel token than to inform the user that the password was leaked :) 
   Use well-known solutions as mentioned public-private key with autentification tokens (token generated with private key + device specified data such as DeviceID etc). Do not store passwords, even encrypted ones.

Comment: 1. I tried to encode photo to base64, send by php POST and then on server decode this string into jpeg..but for large images it was very slow and encoding large bitmaps was too slow and painful in android. So i decided to use FTP.